# Improve performance of a python function

Tags: python, performance, numba

I am new of python and I am looking for a way to speedup the following function that I wrote:

```
def incoming_Wave_Vel(geom,t,phi):

    x = geom[:,0].reshape(1,geom.shape[0])
    y = geom[:,1].reshape(1,geom.shape[0])
    z = geom[:,2].reshape(1,geom.shape[0])
    
    q1 = k*(h+z)
    q2 = omega*t-Kx*x-Ky*y+phi[:,0].reshape(phi.shape[0],1)

    u = AOmega.T @ (np.cosh(q1)/np.sinh(k*h)*np.sin(q2))
    w = AOmega.T @ (np.sinh(q1)/np.sinh(k*h)*np.cos(q2))
        
    return np.vstack((u*np.cos(th),u*np.sin(th),w))*RampFun(t)
```

`AOmega, k, Kx, Ky, omega` and `phi`  are an array of dimensions [n,1], while the dimensions of `x,y,z` are [1,m]. I used the dot product `@` to avoid the sum function but the performance are almost the same.
I tried to use numba but all the tests done until now failed miserably.
Any suggestion to improve the code? Thanks

I post in the following the try to parallelize the function with numba:

```
from numba import njit, prange

@njit(fastmath=True, parallel=True)
def incoming_Wave_Vel_parallel(x,y,z,t,phi):

    u = np.zeros_like(x)
    w = np.zeros_like(x)
    n = len(omega)
    for i in prange(n):
        q1 = k[i]*(h+z)
        q2 = omega[i]*t-Kx[i]*x-Ky[i]*y+phi[i]
        u += AOmega[i]*np.cosh(q1)/np.sinh(k[i]*h)*np.sin(q2)
        w += AOmega[i]*np.sinh(q1)/np.sinh(k[i]*h)*np.cos(q2)
    
    return np.vstack((u*np.cos(th),u*np.sin(th),w))
```

but this version is slower than the serial one.

Comment: Are t, h, omega and th constant floats?

Comment: Oh sorry, t,h and th are constant floats, omega is an array as k

Comment: AOmega is of dimension (n,1), but q1 and q2 are of dimension (n,m), which makes u and v impossible to compute. Did I miss something?

Comment: Sorry again I missed a AOmega.T, that in the script  is few line above the part I posted....so AOmega is [1,n]

Comment: Alright, I have it running! By any chance, would you have any order of magnitude for n and m so we can run more representative tests ?

Comment: At the moment I have n = 237 and m = 420. With this number is about 9 time slower with respect the case with n=1 and m = 420

Comment: I'm getting around 10ms/exec on an i7, which already seems quite good. Is that comparable to what you have on your end?
Only computing (np.cosh(q1)/np.sinh(k*h) once takes it down to ~7ms/exec, as that operation is quite expensive (~30% of the time spent in the function).

Comment: how you profile it?

Comment: `%%time
   ...: v = incoming_Wave_Vel(xyz.T,0,phi)
   ...: 
CPU times: user 7.42 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 7.42 ms
Wall time: 7.06 ms
`...... with `%%%timeit` : `100 loops, best of 5: 5.47 ms per loop
`

Comment: You can run [this snippet](https://gist.github.com/Seon82/60719a0ee165979cdfff6a881e06b903) in a notebook for profiling.

Comment: Would any variable among AOmega, k, Kx, Ky, omega, phi, geom be constant by any chance?

Comment: with your script I get 7.9ms/exec...so in your opinion there is no way to speedup the code?

Comment: AOmega, k, Kx,Ky, omega phi are input data, geom change with time t

Comment: What's the relation between geom and t? I'd like to try running calls to the function in parallel, assuming your use case is running the function for different time values.

Comment: In geom are stored the spatial coordinates of a floating body, you can consider it constant in time, otherwise geom(t) = Rotation(t)*geom(0) + Traslation(t)

Answer (score 0):

We can optimize `incoming_Wave_Vel` by removing redundant calculations of sin and sinh, improving performance by ~28%.

```py
def incoming_Wave_Vel(t,x,y,z):
    q1 = k*(h+z)
    q2 = omega*t-Kx*x-Ky*y+phi_shaped
    sin = np.sin(q2) 
    cos = np.cos(q2)
    cste = (np.cosh(q1)/np.sinh(k*h))*sin
    u = AOmega.T @ cste*sin
    w = AOmega.T @ cste*cos

    return np.vstack((u*np.cos(th),u*np.sin(th),w))*t
```

The performance can be further improved by parallelizing the operations with `multiprocessing`, achieving a 52% performance increase compared with the original:

```py
from multiprocessing import ThreadPool

times = np.linspace(0,1,200)
pool = ThreadPool()
res = pool.map(lambda i: incoming_Wave_Vel(times[i], x[i],y[i],z[i]), range(len(times)))
```

---

Code used for the timing comparisons:

```py
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

n, m = 237, 420
time_steps = 200
times = np.linspace(0,1,200)
AOmega, k, Kx, Ky, omega, phi = [np.random.random((n,1)) for _ in range(6)]
h, th = 1, 1
x = np.random.random((time_steps,1,m))
y = np.random.random((time_steps,1,m))
z = np.random.random((time_steps,1,m))
phi_shaped = phi[:,0].reshape(phi.shape[0],1)


def incoming_Wave_Vel(t,x,y,z):
    q1 = k*(h+z)
    q2 = omega*t-Kx*x-Ky*y+phi_shaped
    sin = np.sin(q2) 
    cos = np.cos(q2)
    cste = (np.cosh(q1)/np.sinh(k*h))*sin
    u = AOmega.T @ cste*sin
    w = AOmega.T @ cste*cos

    return np.vstack((u*np.cos(th),u*np.sin(th),w))*t

def incoming_Wave_Vel_original(t,x,y,z,phi):
    
    q1 = k*(h+z)
    q2 = omega*t-Kx*x-Ky*y+phi[:,0].reshape(phi.shape[0],1)

    u = AOmega.T @ (np.cosh(q1)/np.sinh(k*h)*np.sin(q2))
    w = AOmega.T @ (np.sinh(q1)/np.sinh(k*h)*np.cos(q2))
    
    return np.vstack((u*np.cos(th),u*np.sin(th),w))*t
```

Original:

```py
%%timeit
res = []
for i,t in enumerate(times):
    incoming_Wave_Vel_original(t, x[i], y[i], z[i], phi)
```

Parallel & optimized:

```py
%%timeit
pool = ThreadPool()
res = pool.map(lambda i: incoming_Wave_Vel(times[i], x[i],y[i],z[i]), range(len(times)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions... the second one, concerning the multiprocessig is interesting, but I have to see how to implement it. I am not sure that i can do it, because the function is not called directly in a for cylce but, it is called inside other function, further, the Rotation and traslation, that I cited before, depends by the output of the function itself